# jetty and eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jetty

I'm trying to run a jetty server from a main. It always starts from http://0.0.0.0:8888;
I have changed jetty.xml and added set host to 127.0.0.0
when i run a command on the downloaded jetty files, it starts correctly at 127.0.0.0.
But eclipse keeps on starting at 0.0.0.0. It is running jetty 6.1, not the 8.0 version I have downloaded.
I've changed JETTY_HOME to point to the correct files. It does not work. :(
Need Help

Answer (score 1):

Jetty 8 is in "experimental state" [(see Versions)](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/about.php) and I would recommend you do not use that version if you have a choice.  I would go with version 6 as there was a change in version 7 with name spaces which may result in the behaviour you see.

Question is where that version 6.1 is coming from that you are seeing.  Investigate and report back.

Comment: I was using GWT, the gwt_dev has jetty 6.1 in it. It was using that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using run-jetty-run eclipse plugin. I have written a blog post about how to use it with [DCEVM](http://ssw.jku.at/dcevm/) for hotdeploy. It really improves development time:

[Spring-mvc + Velocity + DCEVM](http://blog.rafaelsanches.com/2012/02/02/spring-mvc-velocity-dcevm/)